# How to write the condition for BOOL values

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is my response

```
1.{

    image = nbYijSxVXDOFGWFk8BhZUpU
    "is_food_in_time_product" = 1;
    "list_price" = "2.8";
    name = Export;

}
2.
{

    image = 0;
    "is_food_in_time_product" = 1;
    "list_price" = 1;
    name = "K\U00e4se";

}

NSString *abc5 = [abc4 valueForKey:@"image"];
NSLog(@"%@",abc5);
```

Here first response image coming data, second response image no data.Then How to write the if condition.

Comment: you have to save the data in abc4????

Comment: abc 4 is NSDictionary????

Comment: abc4 is an Array ?

Comment: abc4 is  total result Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on url you have to do like this:

```
    NSDictionary *responseDataDictionary = responseObject;
    //here responce object is your total data which is coming from server
    NSArray *array = [[responseDataDictionary valueForKey:@"result"] valueForKey:@"products"];
          for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
          {
               NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"image"];
               if([str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
               {
                    NSLog(@"YES");
                    //here you have to add your image as usual to another mutable array
               }else{
                    NSLog(@"NO");
                    // bool value happens means this will execute
                    // Here you have to add custom image ie.placeholder image
               }

          }
    }
```

that's it cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber * isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber *)[abc4 valueForKey:@"image"];
if([isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES)
{
  NSLog(@"Image is available");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Image is not available");
}
```

your response is like this

**1st condition:**

```
 NSDictionary *r1 = @{@"bool" : @(1)};

NSNumber * isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber *)[r1 valueForKey:@"bool"];
if([isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"Image is available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Image is not available");
}
```

**Output1**

Image is available

**2nd condition:**

```
NSDictionary *r1 = @{@"bool" : @(0)};

NSNumber * isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber *)[r1 valueForKey:@"bool"];
if([isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"Image is available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Image is not available");
}
```

**Output2**

Image is not available

Comment: image=0 is BOOL value coming from server

Comment: i am run above code app is crashing show this error[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10746c528'

Comment: NSDictionary *r1 = @{@"bool" : @(1)};
    NSNumber * isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber *)[r1 valueForKey:@"bool"];
    if([isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Image is available");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Image is not available");
    }
your response is like this......

Comment: BOOL success = [[abc4 valueForKey:@"image"] boolValue];
        if(success)
        {
            NSLog(@"no image");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"image");
        }
        if condition is not calling.please help me

Comment: NSMutableArray *abc2 = [response valueForKey:@"result"];  NSMutableArray *abc3 = [abc2 valueForKey:@"products"];              NSString *abc5 = [abc3 valueForKey:@"image"];                                     image there is no data ,nslog=abc5 is 0,so how to write the if condition valuforkey@"image" is BOOL value.

Comment: NSNumber * isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber *)[abc4 valueForKey:@"image"];
        NSLog(@"%@",isSuccessNumber);
        if([isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"Image is available");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Image is not available");
        }       1.image data :ZO/fE8
J947z+H2kxxpOcr7587z7XcX5A1ZQkiMhRD/m+n56tWr/PTTFa7egB/+cok/ffUVH3/   2. image data:0        but executed else condition only if condition is not executed.

Comment: send me the url i have fetch the result properly and send the code how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a `Dictionary` within `Array` that you stored.

```
//Here index is an integer value, showing the index of an array responseArray.
if[responseArray[index][@"image"] intValue]!=0){

    //Load image
}else{
    //Do not load image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether image(data) is nil or not

First you can directly check

```
if (image != nil)
{
  ....
}
else{
  ...
}
```

Then after converting image(data) into string(abc5)

```
if(abc5 length] == 0)
{
   ....
}
else
{
  ....
}
```